# Users can't like my app anymore

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-likebox

I had a like box in my canvas page and it always worked perfectly fine until this month. It decided not to work anymore.

Screenshot:
[image]

This is the piece of code I was using:

```
<fb:like-box href="https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=129443657150865" width="260" show_faces="false" border_color="" stream="false" header="true"></fb:like-box>
```

And a flash game would get whether or not the user pressed like. But now, it gets nothing anymore and the like button won't even show up. What just happened this month?

edit: Meanwhile, I replaced the like button with the one from the game page. It's not the one I wanted, but better than nothing.

Comment: So your like button previously pointed to the app, but now it points to the fan page for the app, is that correct? If so, it's probably better this way, as you can communicate with fans who like the page.

Answer (score 1):

The Like button does not work with your App Profile Page since Facebook removed all App Fan Pages. Instead, you have to create a new Fan Page from the `Advanced` tab of your App Settings (look for `App Page` setting with a `Create Facebook Page` button).

See: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/